# Use window.onbeforeunload to avoid double clicking

Tags: javascript

I tried to override window.onbeforeunload to avoid double submitting while redirecting pages.

```
window.onbeforeunload = disableCurrentWindow;
function disableCurrentWindow()
{
    console.log("Before Disable the contents");
    window.document.body.disabled = true;
    console.log("After Disable the contents");
    return undefined;
}
```

If I return true here it will give default confirmation pop up which I don't need at the moment. I just need to redirect users to next page. But no need to allow double click

Comment: This event allows you to display a message in a confirmation dialog box to inform the user whether he/she wants to stay or leave the current page.

So I really don't think that you clearly "disable" double click by using onbeforeunload event.

Besides Firefox browser will display default popup anyway. That browser doesn't supports user-defined messages.

In other words window.onbeforeunload should be function that returns string.

Comment: @VictorPerov Thanks for your comments. Scenario is as follows, I have links in my application which will redirect users between pages. But sometimes users double click those links and that cause submitting GET requests twice into the server side. I need to avoid it using common behavior to avoid that duplicate submit. Do you have any other workaround to resolve this issue using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable double submit GET requests you can try to update `href` param in each link for short period of time right after click.

For example,

```js
var clickedAt = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        if (!clickedAt) {
            console.log('click allowed, destination: ' + $(this).attr('href'));
            clickedAt = new Date();
            $('a').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('data-href', $(this).attr('href'));
                $(this).attr('href', '#');
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('click masquaraded, destination: ' + $(this).attr('href'));
        }
        return false;
    });
});
setInterval(function() {
    if (typeof $ == 'undefined') return false;
    if (clickedAt && new Date().getTime() - clickedAt.getTime() > 1000) {
        $('a').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('data-href'));
        });
        clickedAt = null;
    }
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#data">data</a> <a href="#value">value</a>
```

But I don't think - that you should do this. Double clicking is not a problem in most cases - it's not a `DDOS` for your web-server (if you see, that double clicks make a lot of load for your web-server - you should reconfigure it, because on production mode, load in any case will be more powerful).

BTW I have used data-href for dumping old href. If you are using those attributes - you can choose another one buffer.

P.S. If your page has a lot of links it can do some very small lags for your customers

Comment: Yes, I can delaythe GET request as above. But it is not feasible solution for production environment. I want to handle a event just before redirecting and need to block the window for second click. I couldn't achieve this using onbeforeunload  since it is returning dialog for user.

Comment: For your production env you shouldn't worry about double clicks, I think. If it hurts your web-server, first of all you should review your backend logic, Or forming GET requests in client-side - in case if there are some user vars